# C++ WinAPI input

Tags: c++, winapi, input

I'm trying to get a Windows/DirectX Input in my little program. I have tried it now for 2 days, but it is not working as expected.

It only recognizes the WM_KEYDOWN message if I asked for the WM_QUIT message before that. I can't find the solution to this weird problem. You can see the code below.

```
while(m_Running)
        {
            if(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL,"QUIT",NULL,MB_OK);
                }
                if(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL,"PRESS",NULL,MB_OK);
                }
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            if(Update() == false)
            {
                m_Running = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Can you provide a complete SSCCE with a clear description of what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: Message loop (peek-translate-dispatch) is not supposed to have `MessageBox` in its body. `MessageBox` will create its own message loop and mess things up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
SSCCE? Here is the full code of this file. [link](http://pastebin.com/9ACgphSB) 
I just want to catch if the user pressed a key. Then i can work with it. But it just activates the "PRESS" Messagebox when i clicked the little "x" on the top left.

Comment: @Dialecticus
I could also write "m_Running = false" and it does work the same...

Comment: The entire code is not here in the question.

Comment: I repeat what @Dialecticus said. Do not call MessageBox. The key-up and other messages will go to the message box. That's why you're not seeing them in your app.

Comment: @RaymondChen
As i said before, i commented all messageboxes already and added a breakpoint at "WM_KEYDOWN". But he does not activate it...

Answer (score 1):

You should move your handlers into a win proc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_QUIT:
        // ....
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        // ....
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And change your loop to:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Also, when you create your window class:

```
myclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
```

Comment: I just made it like this, but it all does not react, if i press a key.. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0twzuxNV)

Comment: This looks like a game and so the standard message loop is often not used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  So what should i use then?

Comment: Usually in a game you don't use `GetMessage`, and you do use `PeekMessage`. And usually keyboard is handled asynchronously.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
I use 'PeekMessage'. He just uses it in his example.

Comment: Didn't realize this was for a game. I posted code for a standard Windows app. Maybe [this article](https://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/writing_the_game_loop.htm) will help you.

Comment: Ok. If even Stackoverflow can't help. I hate programming Windows and directX. I will go back to openGL...
Thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree it often isn't used, but that is a mistake.  Some small changes are needed to interleave message processing with the game clock, for example `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` instead of `GetMessage`.  But there should still be a message loop, if one is using normal controls.

Comment: @Ben I'm not saying the message loop should be dropped. Just that it is sometimes best not to run the loop with GetMessage.

Comment: @Daniel Stack Overflow would help if you asked a better question. The problem is your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the link I posted, I've downloaded Visual Studio Express 2013 and compiled run the following, tested it works.

This contains window and class creation, a message loop, and a windows procedure to process messages.

```
// Trim fat from windows
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 

#include <windows.h>

// Windows Procedure Message Handler
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Switch message, condition that is met will execute*/
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        MessageBox(NULL, "QUIT", NULL, MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        MessageBox(NULL, "PRESS", NULL, MB_OK);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Main function
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  windowClass;        //window class
    HWND        hwnd;               //window handle
    MSG         msg;                //message

    /*  Fill out the window class structure*/
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "MyClass";
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);

    /*  Register window class*/
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /*  Class registerd, so now create window*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,     //extended style
        "MyClass",          //class name
        "A Real Win App",       //app name
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |       //window style
        WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_SYSMENU,
        100, 100,           //x/y coords
        400, 400,           //width,height
        NULL,               //handle to parent
        NULL,               //handle to menu
        hInstance,          //application instance
        NULL);              //no extra parameter's

    /*  Check if window creation failed*/
    if (!hwnd)
        return 0;

    bool done = false; //initialize loop condition variable

    /*  main message loop*/
    while (!done)
    {
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //check for a quit message
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Translate and dispatch to event queue
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I just changed it like this. you can have a look here:

[link](http://pastebin.com/0twzuxNV)

The same Problem. :/

Comment: I can't view paste bin links here. Will try to find a complete tutorial for you.

Comment: I've edited my post to contain a working example of that tutorial above, with the MessageBox calls that you've provided.

Comment: Thats quite funny. i made it exactly like you, but it does not catch KEYDOWN-events.
It's not your code. it has to do something with my whole project

Comment: @Daniel So why don't you make an SSCCE?

Comment: Well the example I've given works fine, I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Express (for Windows Desktop), created a new project under Visual C++ | General | Empty Project. In the solution explorer I've added a new cpp source file, then copy + pasted in code. It builds and runs fine for me. Can you outline the version of OS, IDE, and the exact steps you're using to create the project?